# Data deleting logically from table but still sqlite db file size same

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I am using sqlite database.
I created fresh database and I performed bulk insert of 20K rows in a transaction and then commited the transaction.

Later I perormed delete query

```
delete from Table
```

After deleting, I had opened SQlite Db Browser and checked whether data in table deleted or not. The data in table was deleted. but the size of the file still remains same as the size of the file before executing delete query.

Logically there was no tuples in table as i verified in Db Browser.
But the size of sqlite.db is 4MB approx.
How can i solve this issue.

Comment: In my case whenever user syncs data 4 mb will be created.
So daily db size increasing by 4mb.

Comment: Perhaps this doc on [VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) could help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doc on [VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) helped my problem

The `VACUUM` command rebuilds the database file, repacking it into a minimal amount of disk space.

The VACUUM command works by copying the contents of the database into a temporary database file and then overwriting the original with the contents of the temporary file.